# Как в Delphi объявить константу равную меньшей из двух других?

Tags: delphi, компиляция, delphi-xe5, константа

Для удобства работы, хочу задать некоторые ограничения константами. Например:

```
 const
   MAX_BUFFERS  = 16;
   MAX_SOURCES  = 32;
   MAX_SOUNDS   = 16;
```

Часть из констант со-зависимы. Хочу их связать. Но, вот такой код не работает, т.к. идет обращение к функции:

```
 const
   MAX_BUFFERS  = 16;
   MAX_SOURCES  = 32;
   MAX_SOUNDS   = Min(MAX_BUFFERS, MAX_SOURCES);
```

Каким образом можно присвоить константе значение наименьшее из двух других констант?

Comment: Какая же это константа тогда? вы с статикой путаете?

Comment: Не хотелось бы, т.к. далее по коду нужны именно константы.

Comment: кстати, можно. Какая версия Delphi?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру над константами, при объявлении, разрешена часть действий. Например, можно складывать, вычитать, брать модуль, итп.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В версиях Delphi, в которых появилась директива `$IF` такое сделать можно:

```pascal
const
  cOne = 1;
  cTwo = 2;
  {$IF cOne < cTwo}
  cThree = cOne;
  {$ELSE}
  cThree = cTwo;
  {$IFEND} // возможно, компилятор скажет что эта директива устарела и потребует использовать {$ENDIF}
```

---

При желании, можно записать компактнее, это же дефайны:

```
cThree = {$IF cOne < cTwo} cOne {$ELSE} cTwo {$IFEND};
```

Comment: В ХЕ5 работает, отлично. Щас поищу если нет варианта покомпактнее, то приму ваш )

Comment: Можно покомпактнее, кстати, это же дефайны - `MAX_SOUNDS = {$IF MAX_BUFFERS > MAX_SOURCES}MAX_BUFFERS{$ELSE}MAX_SOURCES{$IFEND};`

Comment: @Kromster - это уже дело вкуса, принцип-то тот же. Мне не нравятся длинные строчки, на мой взгляд - менее наглядно.

Comment: Давайте я дополню, для широты ответа.

Comment: условная компиляция еще 2007й версии была, и вероятно раньше тоже.

Comment: и Delphi7 похоже тоже была

Comment: @teran директивы условной компиляции были очень давно. Но вот директива `{$IF` появилась, если я правильно вижу, в D2009. В `$IFDEF` можно использовать только ранее определенные через `$DEFINE` элементы, а конструкции "обычного" кода недоступны

Comment: @kami я ж тоже не с головы придумал, в справке глянул в 2007й есть примеры с `$IF`. В D7 как то оно вскольз упоминается, непонятно, но я с d7 и не работал никогда, с 2009го как раз и начал.

Comment: @teran значит моя фраза "если я правильно вижу" - неправильна :) Собственно, ответ не противоречит ничему, даже если $IF появилась в D3 - фраза ответа "в которых появилась $IF" достаточно обтекаема. Искать в сети для выяснения деталей hlp файлы к старым делфям что-то не тянет...